# Rails: Best way to validate a model to ensure that a new association is owned by a particular user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm writing a Rails 3.2 application and this type of requirement comes up quite often I'm sure.  In my application I have the following ActiveRecord models:

- User
- Message
- Contacts
- MessageContacts (the has_many through table for message <-> contacts)

I want to make sure that when a user creates a new message, that they can only add their own contacts to the message.  Would love to hear suggestions and or related gems (cancan?) that may make this process DRY.

Below is what I have put together and it appears to work, but would like to know if I'm going about this the right way.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :message_contacts
  has_many :contacts, through: :message_contacts

  validates_each :contacts do |record, attr, contacts|
    contacts.each do |contact|
      record.errors.add(attr, 'must belong to you') if contact.user_id != record.user_id
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code follows accepted style for this kind of situation.

If you don't want an error for each contact the user doesn't own, but just one error for trying to include contacts you don't own, you could do this instead:

```
validates :contacts_ownership

def contacts_ownership
  errors.add(:contacts, 'must belong to you') unless (contacts - user.contacts).empty?
end
```

But it's more a matter of taste and requirements than a preferred method. If you need errors for each contact your way is better. If you just need AN error, this way might be preferable. It also helps you in that it's a bit more readable and easier to test in isolation should you need to.